# View not rendering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webrick

I am trying to render a view from the current one using jquery. I am using flexigrid for my project and I want to code for the info button.

Here is my view. Using jquery I am calling the following,

```
var name = $('.trSelected .sorted div').html();
$.post("/contacts/display_info/", {file_as : name});
```

My controller is the following. Tried debugging also.

```
def display_info
        @contact = Contacts.find_by_file_as(params[:file_as])
        puts "---------------"
        puts @contact.id
        puts "---------------"
        render(:action => 'display_info' , :id => @contact.id)
    end
```

And here is my console:

[image]

Cant figure out what is the problem. Please help!

Comment: why don't you use `redirect_to contact_path(@contact)` instead of `render(:action => 'contacts' , :id => @contact.id)`

Comment: @rony36 It still show that '500 internal server error'.

Comment: is there any view for `contact` action?

Comment: @rony36 oops!! I edited the question. Now its showing rendered 'contacts/display_info'. I edited the question

Comment: errr, what's the problem? You're posting to an action, and the log shows the view for that action getting rendered.

Comment: @sevenseacat The problem is it is not getting rendered in the browser.

Comment: We could see CSRF issue in your log. Just see, if any of these links helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986939/cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-in-rails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039475/rails-3-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273854/rails-ajax-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity

Comment: @RajeshCO he is saying it renders in the rails console but it isnt going thru in the WEB BROWSER..kind of strange

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are doing a ajax request it should prefferably be `JSON`.
2. For Json, check for a file named `contacts.json.erb` in contacts folder.
3. You can try using remote true, much clean and better option than ajax/json requests.

Check this : http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

try putting in your controller

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json=> {:success => true, :id => @contact.id } }
end
```

Something like this.

Comment: No there is nothing of json in that folder.

Comment: @FredoCorleone wat happens if u type the web address u r rendering in the URL?

Comment: @sahil can you plz elaborate? maybe correct my code?
It has to be through jquery because i am using flexigrid

Comment: I edited the question. My action was wrong. Please check it out.

Comment: Its 200 OK. What other problem are you facing ?

Comment: @SahilGrover he is saying it renders in the rails console but it isnt going thru in the WEB BROWSER..kind of strange

Answer (score 0):

in your `layout`, please add:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

and when you are `posting` make sure you are sending:

```
 "authenticity_token": "<%= form_authenticity_token %>"
```

more specifically:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I already have the <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in the 'head'. I cant figure out the place to add the second line. help.

Comment: I have mentioned it in the post.

Comment: I got the answer. it was window.location.replace. And i was goin in completely the wrong direction. Thanks you for assisting!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're making an ajax request, but you're not doing anything with it. You need a callback that will capture the response from the request, and process it in some way.

Something like:

```
$.post("/contacts/display_info/", {file_as : name}, function(data) {
  // `data` will be the HTML returned by the server

  // If for example you want to render this HTML on your page, you may want something like: 
  $('#my_fancy_div').html(data);
});
```

You will also want to change your controller action to be `render layout: false`, presuming you only want to render the HTML in the view, and not the surrounding application layout.

Comment: I want to move the control to '/contacts/display_info/name_of_the_contact'. How do I do that. I am sorry if my question is wrong but can it be done without ajax??

Comment: @sevenseacat he is saying it renders in the rails console but it isnt going thru in the WEB BROWSER..kind of strange

Comment: @sevenseacat I got the answer. it was window.location.replace. And i was goin in completely the wrong direction. Thanks you for assisting!